# How to hide a JsonProperty in the DTO?

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, properties, mapstruct

I am using a DTO for both the insertion of an object and for the search that returns the data.

in particular, I was interested to understand if there is a way to hide some fields:

```
    private List <aDTO> sos;

    private List <aDTO> sosPast;

    private List <aDTO> sosPresentFuture;
```

sos is used in writing to insert a list of objects.
in the research, I need two separate elements, one that returns the past objects, one that returns the present and/or future objects.

so in insertion, I will have to show only

```
    private List <aDTO> sos;
```

in the research, I will have to show only

```
    private List <aDTO> sosPast;
    private List <aDTO> sosPresentFuture;
```

(In research the problem was solved by

```
    @Mapping(target = "sos", ignore = true)
```

in the mapper)

Now I need something to hide the two lists (sosPast and sosPresentFuture) in order to leave only the sos list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution, as mentioned by @tpschmidt, is to split the DTOs.

But if you still want to use the same DTO, you can solve the problem by adding @ReadOnlyProperty and @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true):

```
@JsonProperty("sosPast")
@ReadOnlyProperty
@ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
private List<aDTO> sosPast;

@JsonProperty("sosPresentFuture")
@ReadOnlyProperty
@ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
private List <aDTO> sosPresentFuture;
```

Note that in newer version of swagger-annotations @ApiModelProperty is replaced by @Schema

Answer (score 2):

1. If you want to hide something from Swagger you can use `@ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)`.
2. If you want to completely remove the field from being serialized by jackson you can do `@JsonIgnore` on your response DTO.

Does this help?

Comment: @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true) will remove them (the two lists sosPast and sosPresentFuture) also from the in the research :(                                                                     I Only need to remove them from the insert.

Comment: You should split your DTOs then. One for the incoming request and one for the outgoing response. It's also good regarding separation of concerns :)